# Scala understanding the difference between these two functions

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In a superclass I have a function defined:

```
def render(model: JsonModel) {
    if (!model.isOk()) {
      BadRequest(model.toJsonString()).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    } else {
      Ok(model.toJsonString()).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    }
  }
```

I want to call this function in my subclass:

```
def test(model: JsonModel) = Action { implicit request =>
  render(model)  
}
```

This doesn't work and complains - type mismatch; found : Unit required

if i get rid of the implicit request

```
def test(model: JsonModel) = Action { 
  render(model)  
}
```

It seems to work, but I sometimes I need to have access to the request

Comment: Please add the *full* error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
def render(model: JsonModel) {
```

The `render` method returns `Unit`. I know that without looking at any other line, because it is missing an equals sign. If you wrote it like this:

```
def render(model: JsonModel) = {
```

Then it would return something else, which I expect is what is required.

Comment: Thanks its the little things like that

Comment: @chiappone The procedure syntactical notation is despised by everyone except the numerous group of people that think it is great. As such, it is untouchable, but, personally, I think it is despicable. I think Scala 2.10 will at least have a warning.